# Why does calling NSApplication.shared directly ignore the class specified by the Principal class in Info.plist?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, appkit, nsapplication

I would like to use a custom subclass of [`NSApplication`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication) to create the application instance of my program. The object retrieved by [`NSApplication.shared`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/1428360-shared) or [`NSApp`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapp) should be an instance of the `Application` class below:

```
class Application: NSApplication {
    // My own methods
}
```

I first tried to set *Principal class* in `Info.plist` from `NSApplication` to `Application` but I later learned I had to use [`$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).Application`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77423952/16217248) instead. This worked, and instantiated my subclass as expected, when I tried **in a fresh macOS Application template** with no modifications other than changing the *Principal class* and adding the code to define my subclass.

---

The issue is that the above changes had no effect whatsoever in an existing application project with a different structure.

To reproduce this in the fresh project, I removed the `.xib`/`.storyboard` file, and replaced the `AppDelegate.swift` file with only a `main.swift` file containing the following:

```
import Cocoa
class Application: NSApplication, NSApplicationDelegate {
    func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_ _: NSApplication) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
NSApplication.shared.delegate = (NSApp as! Application)
NSApp.run()
```

In this case, the `as!` downcast will fail, meaning that the application object created by `NSApplication.shared` is not an instance of my custom class, **even though I set the *Principal class* to the same string that worked before.** Removing `Info.plist` entirely seems to have no effect at all.

I suspect that the other project structure comprising a delegate annotated with `@NSApplicationMain` somehow registers the value of *Principal class* in `Info.plist` to be used to instantiate the application instance, but using `NSApplication.shared` to manually initialize the application does not include that step.

How can I use a custom class for my application object in this particular case where I use `NSApplication.shared` directly?

In case this matters my macOS version is 10.15.7 and my Swift version is 5.3.2.

Comment: @jnpdx I tried setting the Principal class to `$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).Application` but that did not work. And using just `Application` but annotating my class with `@objc` does not work either.

Comment: Can you test this in a blank project and make sure there isn't something else that is interfering? My solution worked fine in a blank project.

Comment: @chivracq Of the questions I see that are bounties, especially in the more niche questions such as this one, I am convinced that there is a good chance the question would still go unanswered... maybe one day I will find out the answer myself and post it.

Comment: Yep, well then go for Quality, and your Qt will "one day" get some Answer/Explanation, in some "organic way"... // Removing my 2 previous Comments, you could/should one yourself pointing to the related 'Meta' Qt about this one... And good luck further...!

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure that the `Principal class` includes the correct module name for it to be loaded.

This works fine:

```
@main
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        print("NSApp:", NSApplication.shared as! MyApplication)
    }
}

class MyApplication: NSApplication {
    
}
```

[image]

Which prints:

> NSApp: <CustomClass.MyApplication: 0x12af053b0>

Comment: Indeed. This comes down to the name-mangling applied to Swift code, to keep it compatible with the lack of namespaces in Objective C. An alternative to this is to mangle the name yourself, e.g. `@objc(MyAppName_MyApplication)`, then you can just set `MyAppName_MyApplication` as your principle class.

Comment: @Alexander Why does Swift name-mangle code in the first place?

Comment: @user16217248 To allow for two different modules to define the types with the same name, and not having it be a "duplicate symbol" linker error, like it was in Objective C. That's why you see everyone prefixing their class names in Objective C (e.g. `NS*`, `UI*`, etc. to help mitigate name duplication), but not in Swift.